# Deleting rows where a column does not contain any of 2 strings in Mysql

Tags: mysql, delete-row

What's the command to achieve this:
 MYSQL: delete all rows where "row_name" column does not contain string "foo" or "bar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LIKE` operator here:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE row_name NOT LIKE '%foo%' AND row_name NOT LIKE '%bar%';
```

Using `REGEXP` we can write this a bit more concisely:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE row_name NOT REGEXP 'foo|bar';
```